# find two topological spaces $X , Y$ such that $(X \times X ) \cong (Y\times Y)$ (homeomorphic) but $X \ncong Y$ .

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

find two topological spaces $X , Y$ such that $(X \times X )  \cong (Y\times Y)$ (homeomorphic) but $X   \ncong  Y$ .Here $\cong$ means homeomorphic.

For example i think we can set $X=[0,1]$ and $ Y= [0,1)$.is this answer true?

Comment: $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is compact but $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ is not.

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66007/can-non-homeomorphic-spaces-have-homeomorphic-squares) mathoverflow post. I don't know who is downvoting though and why.